# % of revenue chnage from previous month and previous year of same month - MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions

Input data

```
    Date         State  Revenue 
   31-01-2020     M       100
   05-05-2020     M       500
   05-05-2020     k       500
   31-05-2020     M       100
   12-04-2021     K       250
   15-04-2021     M       300
   20-05-2021     K       250
   21-05-2021     M       300
```

Desired output
Expected Output:

The expected output is expected only for the Month of May'21. Other values can be discarded

```
STATE Total_Revenue  % change of revenue compared to the previous month of the state     % change of revenue compared to same month from previous year for the state
 M
 K
```

Im stuck with the problem and I'm still stuck in learning phase of SQL

Comment: what is State? is k the same as K? what counts as "previous month" (I see you have multiple records per month and even per State & month).  you say Desired output but don't actually show data (other than M and K).

Comment: There are multiple entries per month, how to handle? Sum up? Select most recent one or filter by e.g. state?

Comment: In any case you'll end up self-joining, either tables directly if you are interested in a single revenue or several queries each one grouping by month (or more efficiently a single query introduced once by a `WITH` clause referenced multiple times).

Comment: [Playing around](https://dbfiddle.uk/B0eiJIbr) a little... Note that it won't cover January of this year and December of preceding one, leaving to you to extend accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
State,
SUM(Revenue) AS Total_Revenue,
(SUM(Revenue) - LAG(SUM(Revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY 
MONTH(Date))) / LAG(SUM(Revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY MONTH(Date)) 
* 100 AS `% change of revenue compared to the previous month of the state`,
(SUM(Revenue) - SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN Revenue ELSE 0 
END)) / SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND 
MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) * 
100 AS `% change of revenue compared to same month from previous year for the 
 state`
 FROM
 table_name
 WHERE
 MONTH(Date) = 5 -- Filter for the month of May
 AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) -- Filter for the current year
 GROUP BY
  State;
```

The query uses window functions (LAG) to calculate the revenue change compared to the previous month for each state. It also uses conditional aggregation to calculate the revenue change compared to the same month from the previous year for each state.